# Status read failed in LWP Useragent

Tags: linux, perl, https, operating-system, lwp-useragent

Case 1:
My server (accessing remotely does not have internet access) having the connectivity to the remote server in 443 port. Using web service URL, I need to send the web service request and receive the response. I am able to send the request using but unable to receive the response from remote server.
code:
Here is my code which i am using to send and receive the https request using the lwp agent in perl

```
  use Data::Dumper;
    use LWP::UserAgent;
    use HTTP::Status;
    use HTTP::Response;
    use HTTP::Request::Common;
    $ENV{PERL_LWP_SSL_VERIFY_HOSTNAME} = 0;
    $LWPUserAgent = new LWP::UserAgent( 'timeout' => '20');
    $LWPUserAgent->ssl_opts('verify_hostname' => 0) ;
    $WEB_URL="https://webserviceurl.com/Request?Arg1|Arg2|Arg3|Arg4";
    $Response = $LWPUserAgent->get($WEB_URL);
    print Dumper $Response ;
```

I printed the response using Data::Dumper and getting below response.

```
 $VAR1 = bless( {
                   '_content' => 'Status read failed:  at /usr/share/perl5/Net/HTTP/Methods.pm line 269.',
                     '_rc' => 500,
                     '_headers' => bless( {
                                            'client-warning' => 'Internal response',
                                            'client-date' => 'Tue, 13 Oct 2015 15:13:21 GMT',
                                            'content-type' => 'text/plain'
                                          }, 'HTTP::Headers' ),
                     '_msg' => 'Status read failed: ',
                     '_request' => bless( {
                                            '_content' => '',
                                            '_uri' => bless( do{\(my $o = 'https://webserviceurl.com/Request?Arg1%7Arg2%7Arg3%7Arg4')}, 'URI::https' ),
                                            '_headers' => bless( {
                                                                   'user-agent' => 'libwww-perl/6.04'
                                                                 }, 'HTTP::Headers' ),
                                            '_method' => 'GET'
                                          }, 'HTTP::Request' )
                   }, 'HTTP::Response' );
```

I searched more about this in google and i am unable to found any idea about this.
My server information are :
OS - wheezy 7.2 64bit.
perl 5, version 14, subversion 2 (v5.14.2) built for x86_64-linux-gnu-thread-multi
LWP::UserAgent - 6.04
HTTP::Response,HTTP::Status,HTTP::Request::Common versions are - 6.03.
Case 2: My server (in home and internet access) having the connectivity using my static ip of the internet connection. Using my proxy trying to run the above code with below piece of code.

$LWPUserAgent->proxy('https', 'http://192.168.12.10:3128')  ;

```
I am able to send and receive the https requests using LWP agent and working fine. 
My server information are:
OS - squeeze (6.0.6) 32 bit
perl, v5.10.1 (*) built for i486-linux-gnu-thread-multi
LWP::UserAgent - 6.13
HTTP::Response - 5.836
HTTP::Status - 5.817
HTTP::Request::Common - 5.824

I confused of the these things.
1.OS problem
2.Package versions problem
3.whether is it a bug in wheezy 
If any one can provide me the correct direction to resolve this it would be highly appreciated.
```

Comment: What version of Net::HTTP do you have? That error message doesn't even exist in the latest one.

Comment: Given it's perl `5.10` - which is 6 years old and end of life, I'd imagine it's a not too new version of Net::HTTP either.

Comment: The version of Net::HTTP is 6.03

Comment: In both servers, I am able to send and receive the web service request in  http (80 port) using LWP::UserAgent. But In https (443 port) only i am facing the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Please set `$ENV{HTTPS_DEBUG} = 1;` and write here what the script prints.

Comment: Still it is printing the same. I do not see any difference. Status read failed:  at /usr/share/perl5/Net/HTTP/Methods.pm line 269. 500 Internal error.